# Cannot access object/array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I can console.log and see the array I created but as soon as I attempt to access it, I get undefined.

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    // fetch goal data for display
    let response = await fetchWithToken("http://localhost:8080/api/getGoals");
    let goalData = await response.json();
    goalData = await goalData.filter(skill => skill.Skill === "CS_en");
    // get info from people API with distinct list rather than every row
    let people = new Set([]);
    goalData
      .filter(element => element.UpdatedBy !== null)
      .forEach(element => {
        people.add(element.UpdatedBy);
      });
    people = Array.from(people);
    // call peopleAPI
    const peopleObj = await peopleAPI(people);

    console.log("peopleObj :", peopleObj);
    console.log("peopleObj[0] :", peopleObj[0]);
    }
```

Here is the peopleAPI where I'm calling another api and getting a list of user info.

```
const peopleAPI = people => {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // get people API info
    const peopleObj = [];
    const apiPromises = [];
    if (people) {
      people.forEach(empid => {
        const apiPromise = fetch(
          `https://someApiCall/${empid}`
        )
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            peopleObj.push({
              empid: res.id,
              name: res.name.preferred ? res.name.preferred : res.name.full
            });
          })
          .then(() => apiPromises.push(apiPromise));
      });
      // once all promises have been resolved, return a promise with the peopleObj
      Promise.all(apiPromises).then(() => {
        resolve(peopleObj);
      });
    }
  });
};

export default peopleAPI;
```

Results of console.logs

[image]

Comment: in the first console.log could you do me a favor and instead log `peopleObj.length` and see what it says that is when this function is called?

Comment: Check the **i** which appears immediate right of `peopleObj : []` in the console output. What does it say..? That's exactly why the `async await` abstraction is harmful. Use promises.

Comment: What does `peopleAPI` look like?

Comment: Please show us the implementation of the `peopleAPI` function

Comment: Btw, drop the `await` on the result of that `filter` call

Comment: What you're seeing in the console might actually be the array AFTER it loads; the console doesn't print immediately. Try logging `console.log("peopleObj: ", [].concat(peopleObj))` instead; that will make a copy at the moment you want it, and you can see if that's empty.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code. That function can be optimized greatly. Still not sure why the code doesn't await the result though.

Comment: One thing is that you don't resolve if there are no `people` in `peopleAPI`.

Comment: Jhecht, i = "Value below was evaluated just now"

Comment: Try this instead: https://pastebin.com/dtNVf49C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use push inside `fetch.then`, just return its value, and then push it to apiPromises`

```
const peopleAPI = people => {`
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // get people API info
    const apiPromises = [];
    if (people) {
      people.forEach(empid => {
        const apiPromise = fetch(`https://someApiCall/${empid}`)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            return {
              empid: res.id,
              name: res.name.preferred ? res.name.preferred : res.name.full
            }
          });
        apiPromises.push(apiPromise)
      });
      Promise.all(apiPromises).then((data) => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    }
  });
};

export default peopleAPI;
```

Or even simpler and readable

```
const peopleAPI = people => {`
  const apiPromises = people.map(empid => {
    return fetch(`https://someApiCall/${empid}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => ({
        empid: res.id,
        name: res.name.preferred ? res.name.preferred : res.name.full
     }));
    });
  return Promise.all(apiPromises)
};
```

Comment: `Promise.all()` creates a `Promise`, there's no need to wrap it in one.

Comment: @ChrisG it was OP's attempt, updated to shorter version

Comment: Appreciate everyone's help.  I'm still new to Javascript and trying to work more with async and promises.